# Where is the tree under which Avraham served the malachim?

Tags: abraham, story-identification, chatam-sofer

The Artscroll biography of *[The Chasam Sofer](https://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781422622322.html)* by Yisroel Besser (p.100) relates a story where due to the Chasam Sofer's involvement, an argument that emerged between followers of the Baal Shem Tov and followers of the Vilna Gaon, both of whom were settlers in Eretz Yisroel, was solved amicably.

The anecdote concludes:

> In appreciation for his inolvement and ruling, the Torah community in Eretz Yisroel sent him a precious gift: a piece of a wood cut from the tree believed to be the one under which Avraham Avinu<sup>1</sup> served the *malachim* who came to visit him...

Is the whereabouts of this tree public knowledge? If so, where exactly is this tree located?

---

<sup>1</sup> [Bereishis 18:8](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.18.8?lang=bi&aliyot=0)

> וַיִּקַּ֨ח חֶמְאָ֜ה וְחָלָ֗ב וּבֶן־הַבָּקָר֙ אֲשֶׁ֣ר עָשָׂ֔ה וַיִּתֵּ֖ן לִפְנֵיהֶ֑ם וְהֽוּא־עֹמֵ֧ד עֲלֵיהֶ֛ם **תַּ֥חַת הָעֵ֖ץ** וַיֹּאכֵֽלוּ
>
> He took curds and milk and the calf that had been prepared and set these before them; and he waited on them **under the tree** as they ate.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oak_of_Mamre

Comment: Fascinating @DoubleAA!! Feel free to answer